# Where is the PATH in a Chef Run (Omnibus installation) enforced/configured?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

I am trying to build a development box via Vagrant/Chef-solo, based on Centos 6.4 and using vagrant-omnibus (1.1.2) to ensure the box is using the latest Chef (while creating/putting together the cookbooks, then I'll probably freeze the version). Currently it installs 11.8.2.

One of the cookbooks is using `ruby_build` to install Ruby 2.0.0-p353 and then create symlinks under /usr/local/bin so that Ruby is available to all users after the chef run is complete. It also installs some gems which installation I want to enforce system-wide.

The thing is that using the `gem_package` resource after the `ruby_build` execution installs the gem in the embedded ruby from the Chef Omnibus installation. Until now I worked around that using the `gem_binary` option to force the detection of the system-wide Ruby environment but it got me thinking and so I checked which PATH is used during the Chef run (using a `shell_out` to print the PATH to a file) and found out it shows the following:

`/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/chef/embedded/bin:/opt/chef/embedded/bin:/usr/local/bin`

Where does that come from? How/Why is `/opt/chef/embedded/bin` added **before** `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: I guess it is configured when Chef is installed and it's not connected with chef-run in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

1. Vagrant uses `ssh` to log in to the `guest` box as the 'vagrant' user. This adds the `sshd_config` secure path. In CentOS 6.4 that's:

   `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`
2. Then it uses `sudo` to become the 'root' user. The profile get's sourced and in CentOS 6.4 that means `sbin` paths are prepended, while `$HOME/bin` is appended.
3. Then `chef-solo` runs and path sanity is enforced. Path sanity appends all paths (if not part of the existing `$PATH`) at the end, starting with `ruby_bindir` and `gem_bindir` (which refer to the Chef Omnibus installation). Then, every other sane path is appended if not part of `$PATH` already, which is why `/usr/local/bin` is at the very end.

As Mark O'Connor mentioned, for `gem_package` the `gem_binary` option can be used to for a certain gem. For other resources the full path can be specified. For `shell_out!` though, if a command is to be executed as a user with a login shell first the environment needs to be emptied `(enviroment: { 'PATH' => nil }` and `bash -l -c` used to execute the desired command.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend specifying the path to the gem command of the target ruby:

```
gem_package "mypackage" do
  gem_binary "/path/to/my/ruby/distro/bin/gem"
end
```

Comment: @tnarik It's more than a work-around. The only way to be certain that chef installs the gem in the correct place is to use this approach, coupled of course with a "package" declaration that installs the desired version of ruby on your system. In our case we had to create our own RPM ruby distros.

Comment: Well, in the case of ```gem_package``` I would like for it to be installed in whatever is the system-wide default Ruby installation, and a gem_binary points to a specific one. But it works. My question though was more about the mechanism that mandates the PATH that Vagrant/Chef-Solo uses in general, ```gem_package``` was what made me look into it.